# Сделать сложную выборку элементов в jquery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть вот такой фрагмент верстки:

```
<div class="1">
<a href="#">Some link</a>
<span><input class="selected/unselected"></span>
</div>
```

Хотел спросить как можно выбрать див класс 1 если у него внутри будет инпут селектед (т.е если внутри дива находится инпут селектед, то див должен становиться тоже селектед), и убирать класс если инпут станет анселектед. Инпуты меняют свой класс если кликать на другую кнопку на сайте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('div.1').each(function(){
    if($.contains(this, $('input.selected', this)[0]))
        $(this).addClass('selected');
});
$('div.1 input').live('focusin focusout', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('selected unselected').closest('div.1').toggleClass('selected unselected');
});
```

Comment: Очень понравилось Ваше решение, большое спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Если код будет такой:

```
<div class="1 unselected">
    <a href="#">Some link</a>
    <span><input class="selectable unselected"></span>
</div>
```

То на JQuery будет примерно такой обработчик:

```
$('div.1>span>input.selectable').live('focus blur', function(event) {
$(event.target).toggleClass('selected unselected');

var $parent = $(event.target)
    .parent()
    .parent();

if($parent.hasClass('1'))
{
    $parent.toggleClass('selected unselected');
}

});
```

глянуть можно [тут](http://jsfiddle.net/ZmAaw/2/)

Answer (score 0):

А почему нельзя ставить класс сразу на div, а на input вообще не ставить? Сейчас вы хотите, вместо решения одной проблемы, создать новую.

Comment: нельзя на див сразу вешать, там на сайте некоторый функционал, долго рассказывать

Comment: Ну теперь не некоторый будет :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.1 input').each(function(){
    $(this).closest('div.1').addClass( $(this).hasClass('selected')?'selected':'' );
    $(this).closest('div.1').removeClass( $(this).hasClass('selected')?'':'selected' );
});
```